# python urllib post question

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

im making some simple python post script but it not working well.

there is 2 part to have to login.

first login is using 'http://mybuddy.buddybuddy.co.kr/userinfo/UserInfo.asp' this one.

and second login is using 'http://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/usercheck/UserCheckPWExec.asp'

i can login first login page, but i couldn't login second page website.

and return some error 'illegal access' such like .

i heard this is related with some cooke but i don't know how to implement to resolve this problem.

if anyone can help me much appreciated!! Thanks!

```
import re,sys,os,mechanize,urllib,time
import datetime,socket


params = urllib.urlencode({'ID':'ph896011', 'PWD':'pk1089' })
rq = mechanize.Request("http://mybuddy.buddybuddy.co.kr/userinfo/UserInfo.asp", params)
rs = mechanize.urlopen(rq)
data = rs.read() 

logged_fail = r';history.back();</script>'  in data                                             
if not logged_fail:
 print 'login success'
 try:
  params = urllib.urlencode({'PASSWORD':'pk1089'})
  rq = mechanize.Request("http://user.buddybuddy.co.kr/usercheck/UserCheckPWExec.asp", params )
  rs = mechanize.urlopen(rq)
  data = rs.read()
  print data
 except:
  print 'error'
```

Comment: The biggest problem is your last two lines `except: print 'error'`. Get rid of those and you'll have some useful information instead of swallowing all exceptions.

Comment: i was removed except: print 'error' but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

You can't use selenium? IMHO it's better do automation with this.

For install utilize:

```
pip install selenium
```

A example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
# open site
browser.get('http://google.com.br')
# get page source
browser.page_source
```

A login example:

```
# different methods to get a html item
form = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
username = browser.find_element_by_id('input_username')
password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=password]')
username.send_keys('myUser')
password.send_keys('myPass')
form.submit()
```